# Regrouping javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the below javascript array with me

```
var test =[{
Maths:{
    ST1:10,
    ST2:2,
    ST3:15}
},
{
Science:{
    ST1:50,
    ST3:40}
    }
]
```

I want to generate the array shown below out of this

```
var t = [{ST1:{
               Maths:10,
               Science:50
              },
          ST2:{
               Maths:2,
               Science:0
              },
          ST3:{
               Maths:15,
               Science:40
              }
         }]
```

I tried using the code shown below

```
for (var key in test) {
  if (test.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  for (var key1 in test[key]){
    //console.log(key1)}
    var abc = test[key][key1];
    for(var x in abc)
    {

    console.log(x+key1+abc[x])

    }

    }
  }
}
```

I am new to this help me doing this.

Comment: There's no JSON in your question. I think your use of that term is causing confusion.

Comment: Edit you post as `post.replace('JSON', 'Object');`

Answer (score 1):

This does mostly what you want...

```
var t = {};
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    for (var name in test[i]) {
        for (var level in test[i][name]) {
            if (!t[level])
                t[level] = {}
            t[level][name] = test[i][name][level]
        }
    }
}
```

Only thing missing is to get the `Science:0` for when a `STx` value is missing under a section.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/eHwBC/

*Result:*

```
{
    "ST1": {
        "Maths": 10,
        "Science": 50
    },
    "ST2": {
        "Maths": 2
    },
    "ST3": {
        "Maths": 15,
        "Science": 40
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that there's no guaranteed order when using `for-in` for enumeration.

If the labels (Math, Science, etc) are known in advance, then you can ensure that each object gets all labels.

If not, a separate loop can be done. Depending on the approach, it could be done before or after this main loop.

Comment: Oops... You wanted it wrapped in an Array. Add `t = [t]` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

### Do you know about `JSON.stringify(t)`?

It will convert an object literal to JSON.

Mozilla's documentation of this function is available at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify.

You can also read [this blog article](http://cjihrig.com/blog/native-browser-support-for-json-part-2-of-2/) for further explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```
/* Iterator start */
var t = {};
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {  //Iterate Maths, Science,..   
    for (var key in test[i]) {           //Iterate Math
        for (var iKey in test[i][key]) { //Iterate ST1, ST2, ST3
          var s = (t.hasOwnProperty(iKey))?t[iKey]:createObject();                    
          s[key] = test[i][key][iKey];
          t[iKey] = s;
        }
    }
}
/* Iterator End */ 

p = [];
p.push(t);
//^- p is what you want

// Separate function so you can add more items later without changing logic
function createObject () {
    return {'Maths' : 0, 'Science': 0};
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xWGsP/4/) and Proof below,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var test =[{
Maths:{
    ST1:10,
    ST2:2,
    ST3:15
    }
},
{
Science:{
    ST1:50,
    ST3:40}
    }
];

var result = [];
for(i = 0; i <= test.length; i++){
  var resultRow = {};
  for(key in test[i]){
    for(subKey in test[i][key]){
      if(resultRow[subKey] == undefined){
        resultRow[subKey] = {};
      }
      resultRow[subKey][key] = test[i][key][subKey];
    }
  }
  result.push(resultRow);
}
```